# Structural block not working

Tags: layout-update

I am trying to create a structural block on login page using below code.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account_login translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="custom_test" as="custom_test"/>
    </reference>

        <reference name="custom_test">
        <block type="cms/block" name="test">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>test</block_id></action>
        </block> 
        </reference>

    </customer_account_login>
</layout>
```

I have tried below code as well.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account_login translate="label">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="custom_test" as="custom_test"/>

        <reference name="custom_test">
        <block type="cms/block" name="test">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>test</block_id></action>
        </block> 
        </reference>

    </customer_account_login>
</layout>
```

Both the codes are not working.
Block with Id "test" is there and is enabled.
Template login.phtml is loading fine.
No related issues in logs.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Is the block loading? Is there a static block with the id 'test'? Does the 'login.phtml' template load? Any errors in the error log? Simply stating "both the codes are not working" doesn't help much.

Comment: I have update my question.

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing to `root` block which is not `core/text_list` block, so all children blocks are not displayed automatically. You can add `getChildHtml('custom_test')` to your root's template or you can change `reference="root"` to `reference="content"` (you don't need to modify the template).

Moreover, you can simplify your code:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<customer_account_login translate="label">
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="custom_test" as="custom_test">
        <block type="cms/block" name="test">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>test</block_id></action>
        </block> 
    </block>
</reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation but I want to display my block in between register and login form and using above code I am not able to do so